# PC gets IP address from the Help Desk, and when it goes back to related department with different VLAN, no connection

Tags: cisco, vlan, dhcp

Assume the Help Desk is in VLAN 2 and Sales is in VLAN 5.

When PCs come to the Help Desk for troubleshooting, for example a fresh install of Windows, they get an IP address in the subnet of VLAN 2.

A PC carries it's IP address back to the related department when it's transferred there because of the DHCP IP release time.

The problem is that the given IP address is not valid in the destination VLAN (VLAN 5 in this example).

What's the best strategy (Cisco switch configurations or our Microsoft DHCP server) to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: This is a problem with your DHCP server or the end device (PC). It has nothing to do with the network devices. You should ask on [sf] since it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the PC from the Help Desk to the related department, it should release its VLAN 2 IP address as soon as you disconnect it (assuming it is cabled) and it should get a new lease in VLAN 5 when it is reconnected.

If it is receiving an address via a Wireless LAN connection, then it may be that you have the same SSID on two different APs attached to two different VLANs, which will cause you several problems.